# Rails too many queries?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Just doing some Rails and noticed that when displaying 30 products on a single page using `@products.each do` it appears as though there are a lot of queries going on in the background, see below for my console output. Is this right or am I reading this entirely wrong?

```
Category Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."name" = 'bras') LIMIT 1
  Product Load (28.0ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE ("products".category_id = 48)
  Brand Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 408) LIMIT 1
  Category Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."id" = 48) LIMIT 1
  Merchant Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE ("merchants"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered products/_product.html.erb (16.9ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 408) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."id" = 48) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE ("merchants"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered products/_product.html.erb (1.8ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 408) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."id" = 48) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE ("merchants"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered products/_product.html.erb (1.5ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 408) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."id" = 48) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE ("merchants"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered products/_product.html.erb (1.5ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 408) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."id" = 48) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE ("merchants"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered products/_product.html.erb (1.5ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 408) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."id" = 48) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE ("merchants"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered products/_product.html.erb (1.5ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 408) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."id" = 48) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE ("merchants"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered products/_product.html.erb (1.5ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 408) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."id" = 48) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE ("merchants"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered products/_product.html.erb (1.5ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 408) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."id" = 48) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE ("merchants"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered products/_product.html.erb (1.7ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 408) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."id" = 48) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE ("merchants"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered products/_product.html.erb (1.4ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 408) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."id" = 48) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE ("merchants"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered products/_product.html.erb (1.5ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 408) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."id" = 48) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE ("merchants"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered products/_product.html.erb (1.4ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 408) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."id" = 48) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE ("merchants"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered products/_product.html.erb (1.5ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 408) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."id" = 48) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE ("merchants"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered products/_product.html.erb (1.5ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 408) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."id" = 48) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE ("merchants"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered products/_product.html.erb (1.6ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 408) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."id" = 48) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE ("merchants"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered products/_product.html.erb (1.5ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 408) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."id" = 48) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE ("merchants"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered products/_product.html.erb (1.5ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 408) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."id" = 48) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE ("merchants"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered products/_product.html.erb (1.5ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 408) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."id" = 48) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE ("merchants"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered products/_product.html.erb (1.5ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 408) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."id" = 48) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE ("merchants"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered products/_product.html.erb (1.6ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 408) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."id" = 48) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE ("merchants"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered products/_product.html.erb (1.4ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 408) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."id" = 48) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE ("merchants"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered products/_product.html.erb (1.5ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 408) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."id" = 48) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE ("merchants"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered products/_product.html.erb (1.5ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 408) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."id" = 48) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE ("merchants"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered products/_product.html.erb (2.0ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 408) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."id" = 48) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE ("merchants"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered products/_product.html.erb (1.4ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 408) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."id" = 48) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE ("merchants"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered products/_product.html.erb (1.5ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 408) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."id" = 48) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE ("merchants"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered products/_product.html.erb (1.5ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 408) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."id" = 48) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE ("merchants"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered products/_product.html.erb (1.6ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 408) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."id" = 48) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE ("merchants"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered products/_product.html.erb (1.5ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 408) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."id" = 48) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE ("merchants"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
```

Update: Sorry I am specifically talking about the CACHE lines, do these mean these queries are not run everytime?

```
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE ("brands"."id" = 408) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."id" = 48) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE ("merchants"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
```

Here is the code from the product partial:

```
<h3><%= product.product_name %></h3>

<img src="<%= product.image %>" align="right" alt="<%= product.product_name %>" height="200" />

<p><%= truncate(product.product_description, :length => 300, :omission => "...") %></p>

<p><%= product.price %></p>

<p>Brand: <%= product.brand.brand_name %></p>

<p>Category: <%= product.category.category_name %></p>

<p>Merchant: <%= product.merchant.merchant_name %></p>

<p><a href="<%= product.link %>" target="_blank">More information</a></p>

<hr />
```

Comment: There's more to the code. Show us the parts where it references categories, brands and merchants from the product partial please.

Comment: Can you post products/_product.html.erb? Also the relevant controller bit where you setup the collection that you are looping over would be good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to eager load your products/merchants/etc

```
@product = Product.find(conditions, :include => {:category, :brand, :merchant})
```

(I don't know your relations so use as needed)

EDIT in regards to your cache question, no those queries aren't run against the server, but you should definitely look into eager loading so you don't have unnecessary querying going on

For more details see the following

http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/29-fix-n-1-queries

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html <- See Eager loading

Comment: @Jimmy: under the hood, does this just "SELECT" the specified fields as opposed to all "*"?

Comment: @zinc, what this does is load objects for each product that represent the associated models, so you rails doesn't have to go back to the database when it starts turning the view into HTML to get the details of `product.merchant.*` or `product.category.*`

Comment: @zinc, it will load all fields.

Answer (score 2):

Those CACHEd queries are only run once but you still want to join them in initially. In your controller, you will want to do `@products = Product.all(:include => [:brand, :category, :merchant])`

Also, it is a little bit expensive to repeatedly render a small partial. I have had better luck making the partials themselves loop over the collection:

products/_products.html.erb

```
<% products.each do |product| %>
<h3><%= product.product_name %></h3>

<img src="<%= product.image %>" align="right" alt="<%= product.product_name %>" height="200" />

<p><%= truncate(product.product_description, :length => 300, :omission => "...") %></p>

<p><%= product.price %></p>

<p>Brand: <%= product.brand.brand_name %></p>

<p>Category: <%= product.category.category_name %></p>

<p>Merchant: <%= product.merchant.merchant_name %></p>

<p><a href="<%= product.link %>" target="_blank">More information</a></p>

<hr />
<% end %>
```